# Use more than one iBeacon

Tags: swift, cllocation, beacon

my project about beacon that show image when it's closest to the beacon and when it's go to another beacon it's show another image. am trying to solve this problem by using if statement by I don't know what to do it's show me error.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if BEACON_1_UUID = BEACON_1_MAJOR {

        var closestBeacon = beacons[0]

      //  print("major = \(closestBeacon.major) minor = \(closestBeacon.minor)")

        if closestBeacon != lastFoundBeacon || lastProximity != closestBeacon.proximity {
                lastFoundBeacon = closestBeacon
                lastProximity = closestBeacon.proximity

                var  proximityMessage: String!

                switch lastFoundBeacon.proximity {

                case CLProximity.Immediate:

                    if BEACON_1_MAJOR = closestBeacon {
                        proximityMessage = "Very Close"
                        txtDesc.text = "hi"
                        imageview.image = UIImage(named: "CC_Zoe-Francois_No-Bake-Strawberry-Cheesecake.jpg");
                        self.checkIn("Leaving", comment: "Checking In")
                        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                        txtre.text! += "Very Close to \(closestBeacon.major) \(closestBeacon.minor) \n"
                    } else { /* ... */ }

                case CLProximity.Near:
                    proximityMessage = "Near"
                    // manager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(bRegion)
                    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
                   txtre.text! += "Near \(closestBeacon.major) \(closestBeacon.minor) \n"

                case CLProximity.Far:
                    proximityMessage = "Far"

                    txtre.text! += "Far from \(closestBeacon.major) \(closestBeacon.minor) \n"

                    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

                    //self.checkIn("out")
                    self.sendNotification("Good Bye")

                default:
                    proximityMessage = "Where's the Beacon?"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all add error that you have, next explain are you have only two beacons with `major` and `minor` that you know and two images for it, or you have a lot of beacons and you want to change pictures every time user come to it?

Comment: This is maybe not related to your question but will likely drive you into issues too. `BEACON_1_UUID = BEACON_1_MAJOR` is an assignment, not a comparison. For a comparison use `==` but I doubt you want to compare a becon's UUID with its major cause they are quite unlikely to be ever the same.